# Remover Setinhas do EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Criei minha classe com o tipo `int`

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o Numero")]
[DisplayName("Numero")]
public int Number { get; set; }
```

e ai no *Layout* gerou estas setinhas, como faço para remover as setinhas?

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da `view`:

```
<!--Number-->
<div class="alinhado col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class=" alinhadoLabel">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Number,
                        htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        </div>
        <div class="alinhadoEditor">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Number, 
                  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Number, "", 
                  new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--End Number-->
```

Comment: Essa notação ocorre naturalmente pelo fato de você estar usando inteiros na hora de definir seus campos. As setas permitem que seu usuário possa facilmente incrementar ou decrementar o valor do campo. Não é uma funcionalidade do ASP.NET MVC em si ou do Razor, mas do HTML5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloque [`TextBoxFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx) no lugar de [`EditorFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee402949(v=vs.118).aspx). O [`TextBoxFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx) gera um [`input`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) `text`, enquanto [`EditorFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee402949(v=vs.118).aspx) gera [`input`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) de acordo com o tipo existente no seu modelo que pode ser `color`, `date`, `datetime`, `datetime-local`, `email`, `month`, `number`, `range`, `search`, `tel`, `time`, `url` e `week` que são na verdade as [***Tags Html5***](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp), ou seja, o [`EditorFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee402949(v=vs.118).aspx) gera o `input` de acordo com o tipo, tem vantagens nesse aspecto, ***já visto que se o tipo mudar automaticamente se adequa ao novo tipo, alterando então o `type` do*** [`input`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp).

Não existe uma forma de tirar as setas no seu caso, porque [`EditorFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee402949(v=vs.118).aspx) gera um [`input`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) desse tipo:

```
<input type="number" name="Number" />
```

sendo um [`input`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) do `type` `number` ([`Html5`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5)) que possui a características de aceitar números e as setas uma facilidade para o usuário aumentar ou diminuir o valor já existente.

A única forma de contornar isso é colocar um [`TextBoxFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx) que gera um [`input`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) assim:

```
<input type="text" name="Number" />
```

que é no caso um `input` simples do tipo `text`.

***Referencias:***

- [Difference between Html.EditorFor and Html.TextboxFor in ASP.NET MVC?](http://abundantcode.com/difference-between-html-editorfor-and-html-textboxfor-in-asp-net-mvc/)
- [EditorFor Vs TextBoxFor in MVC](http://codigosimples.net/2016/03/14/editorfor-vs-textboxfor-em-mvc/)
- [TextBoxFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx)
- [EditorFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee402949(v=vs.118).aspx)
- [tag input html5](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)
- [HTML5](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5)

Answer (score 1):

Outra maneira é adicionar este código CSS:

```
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
```

Retirado [desta resposta do SO Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23374725/666104).